# how to make dynamic form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I am having a status Field which has 3 options 1)activated 2)rejected 3)pending.If user select rejected status then he has to enter reason for rejection else that reason field should be hidden.Or when user choices rejected i should redirect it to some other form  so that i can send email using the rejection reason

Answer (score 2):

Here are some helpful links

[B-list post about it](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/)

[The Uswaretech post about it](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/10/dynamic-forms-with-django/)